Why doesn't WebViewWidget center vertically in Flutter?
I am building a Flutter widget with a centered WebViewWidget inside a Stack, which should display an ad. However, the WebViewWidget doesn't center vertically within the Stack, even though I used Alignment.center on the Stack widget. Here is my code:
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:thitsarparami/size_config.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class CustomAdWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomAdWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<CustomAdWidget> createState() => _CustomAdWidgetState();
}

class _CustomAdWidgetState extends State<CustomAdWidget> {
  WebViewController? controller;
  bool isLoading = true;
  bool isInitialLoad = true;
  bool isAdFailed = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Initialize after the widget is built to ensure no timing issues.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      initializeWebView();
    });
  }

  void initializeWebView() {
    // Initialize the WebViewController if it's still null
    controller ??= WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
            if (mounted) {
              setState(() {
                isLoading = true;
                isAdFailed = false;
              });
            }
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            if (mounted) {
              setState(() {
                isLoading = false;
                isInitialLoad = false;
              });
            }
          },
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
            if (mounted) {
              setState(() {
                isLoading = false;
                isAdFailed = true;
              });
            }
            if (kDebugMode) {
              print("Failed to load ad: ${error.description}");
            }
          },
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (!isInitialLoad && request.url.startsWith('http')) {
              _launchURL(request.url);
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      );

    // Load the request if the controller was initialized successfully
    if (controller != null) {
      controller!.loadRequest(
        Uri.dataFromString(
          '''
          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html lang="en">
            <head>
              <meta charset="UTF-8" />
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
              <title>Ad</title>
              <style>
                body,
                html {
                  margin: 0;
                  padding: 0;
                  overflow: hidden;
                  background-color: transparent;
                  height: 100%;
                  display: flex;
                  justify-content: center;
                  align-items: center;
                }
                iframe {
                  width: 100%;
                  height: 100%;
                  border: 0;
                }
              </style>
            </head>
            <body>
              <iframe id='a0659fc9' name='a0659fc9' src='https://ads.thitsarparami.org/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=1&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' width='300' height='250' allow='autoplay'><a href='https://ads.localhost.org/www/delivery/ck.php?n=a64097b3&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' target='_blank'><img src='https://ads.thitsarparami.org/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=1&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE&amp;n=a64097b3' border='0' alt='' /></a></iframe>

            </body>
          </html>
          ''',
          mimeType: 'text/html',
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Define the WebView size
    final double webViewWidth = 320.0.w; // WebView's exact width
    final double webViewHeight = 250.0.w; // WebView's exact height
    final double padding = 16.0.w; // Padding inside the border

    // Outer container dimensions (WebView size + padding on each side)
    final double containerWidth = webViewWidth + (2 * padding);
    final double containerHeight = webViewHeight + (2 * padding);

    return Container(
      width: containerWidth,
      height: containerHeight,
      // margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0.w),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0.w),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          // WebView content or fallback view
          SizedBox(
            width: webViewWidth,
            height: webViewHeight,
            child: controller != null && !isAdFailed
                ? WebViewWidget(controller: controller!)
                : (isAdFailed
                    ? Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "Ad could not be loaded. Please check your internet connection.",
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      )
                    : const SizedBox.shrink()),
          ),

          // CircularProgressIndicator for loading state
          if (isLoading)
            const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),

          // "Ad" label in the top-right corner
          Positioned(
            top: 5.0.w,
            right: 5.0.w,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0.w, vertical: 2.0.w),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0.w),
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Ad',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 12.0.w,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _launchURL(String url) async {
    var targetURL = Uri.parse(url);
    if (await canLaunchUrl(targetURL)) {
      await launchUrl(targetURL);
    } else {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Could not launch $url');
      }
    }
  }
}



Using a Center widget inside the Stack can sometimes help ensure the child widget is centered. Replace alignment: Alignment.center with a Center widget directly wrapping the SizedBox
Center(
  child: SizedBox(
    width: webViewWidth,
    height: webViewHeight,
    child: controller != null && !isAdFailed
        ? WebViewWidget(controller: controller!)
        : (isAdFailed
            ? Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Ad could not be loaded. Please check your internet connection.",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              )
            : const SizedBox.shrink()),
  ),
),


Yes, I did but no luck. Fortunately Alignment.bottomCenter is work. I need to understand more  about Stack. Thanks for you comment.
